# Controlling tty / terminal output from other session / shell

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, session, tty

We are told that a tty can control at most one session and furthermore that ttys can be controlled not to allow background process groups within its controlled session to write or read from it, the former being controlled by the `TOSTOP` option.

However, what is the position on other sessions writing to a tty? Can it be controlled in some way? Assume `tty1` and `tty2`, both with shells. I was surprised that the following command on `shell2` on `tty2`...

```
ls > /dev/tty1
```

...actually produced the output from `ls` on `tty1`, no matter what the `TOSTOP` option was set to in `tty1`. Since `shell2` is altogether part of another session, I figured that might be it, because the `TOSTOP` option indeed does what it's supposed to when attempting to write from a background process group. Could someone enlighten me what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TOSTOP` option (described for instance in *[Unix Power Tools](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch12_07.htm)*, or *[Linux csh script going to Suspended (tty output) when running with & (bg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186178/linux-csh-script-going-to-suspended-tty-output-when-running-with-bg)*) refers to a shell's *background* processes.  In this situation, the foreground and background have a *known* relationship.

However, if your process has opened a terminal, it (almost always) has permissions on it, and another process owned by you (running in a different terminal) which does *not* have that relationship could open the same device and write to it.

Comment: The known relationship being that they have the same session id that is? So it would then follow that the tty driver checks this, and if they're not in the same session, it would allow a write if the user permissions allow it?

Comment: That's my impression, yes - perhaps known to the tty driver as having the same *controlling terminal*.

Comment: Well, seems about correct, I tried writing to a tty owned by root instead and then it wouldn't allow me, thanks!